# Finding matches between start nodes for common sources in neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

As part of some analysis, I am trying to find targets that have more than 80% common origins for one-hop paths.

The data is of the kind: all nodes are systems, and the only relationship that is relevant is `ConnectsTo`.

So, I can write queries like

```
match (n:system)-[r:ConnectsTo]->(m:system) return n,m
```

to get the sources `n` for system `m`.

I am looking to find all systems m that have 80% or more common source systems.

Please advise how this could be done for all systems. I tried with collect but am afraid I couldn't write the proper iteration.

Comment: The title of the question says "common targets". Did you mean "common sources"?

Comment: Yes, I did, thanks for this clarification - correcting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's start by creating a simple example data set:

```
CREATE
  (s1:System {name:"s1"}), 
  (s2:System {name:"s2"}), 
  (s3:System {name:"s3"}), 
  (s4:System {name:"s4"}), 
  (s5:System {name:"s5"}), 
  (s1)-[:ConnectsTo]->(s3),
  (s1)-[:ConnectsTo]->(s4),
  (s2)-[:ConnectsTo]->(s3),
  (s2)-[:ConnectsTo]->(s4),
  (s2)-[:ConnectsTo]->(s5)
```

This result in the following graph.

[image]

We start from node pairs (`m1` and `m2`) that have at least a single common source. We calculate:

- the number of sources for each node (`sources1Count` and `sources2Count`)
- the number of common sources (`commonSources`)

Then we compare the number of common sources to the number of sources for the nodes. This could use a bit of fine-tuning, based on what you consider "80% common". The `toFloat` function is required to avoid type mismatches.

The query:

```
MATCH (m1)<-[:ConnectsTo]-()-[:ConnectsTo]->(m2)
MATCH
  (n1)-[:ConnectsTo]->(m1),
  (n2)-[:ConnectsTo]->(m2)
WITH m1, m2, COUNT(DISTINCT n1) AS sources1Count, COUNT(DISTINCT n2) AS sources2Count
MATCH (m1)<-[:ConnectsTo]-(n)-[:ConnectsTo]->(m2)
WITH m1, m2, sources1Count, sources2Count, COUNT(n) AS commonSources
WHERE
  // we only need each m1-m2 pair once
  ID(m1) < ID(m2) AND
  // similarity
  commonSources / 0.8 >= sources1Count AND
  commonSources / 0.8 >= sources2Count
RETURN m1, m2
ORDER BY m1.name, m2.name
```

This gives the following results.

```
╒══════════╤══════════╕
│m1        │m2        │
╞══════════╪══════════╡
│{name: s3}│{name: s4}│
└──────────┴──────────┘
```

PS. for checking the similarity, you could use something like:

```
sources1Count <= toInt(commonSources / 0.8) >= sources2Count
```

This avoids the duplication of `0.8` but does not look very nice.

*Update:* an idea from InverseFalcon in the comments: use `SIZE` instead of `MATCH` and `COUNT`

```
MATCH (m1)<-[:ConnectsTo]-()-[:ConnectsTo]->(m2)
WITH m1, m2, SIZE(()-[:ConnectsTo]->(m1)) as sources1Count, SIZE(()-[:ConnectsTo]->(m2)) as sources2Count
MATCH (m1)<-[:ConnectsTo]-(n)-[:ConnectsTo]->(m2)
WITH m1, m2, sources1Count, sources2Count, COUNT(n) AS commonSources
WHERE
    // we only need each m1-m2 pair once
    ID(m1) < ID(m2) AND
    // similarity
    commonSources / 0.8 >= sources1Count AND
    commonSources / 0.8 >= sources2Count
RETURN m1, m2
ORDER BY m1.name, m2.name
```

Comment: Thank you, I'm trying this now with my data set and will revert

Comment: It's taking quite a while because my data set is pretty big, I've put in a filter on m2, but still running...

Comment: I see - how big is your data set, i.e. how many nodes and relationships do you have? 
Neo4j gives a warning about making a Cartesian product for the second `MATCH` clause, but 1. the second match is required due to the [uniqueness of relationships](http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/#cypherdoc-uniqueness) in Cypher 2. we are not calculating a huge Cartesian product here. Did you try filtering `m2` in the first `MATCH`, like `(m2 { some_attribue: some_value })`?

Comment: I tried a where clause for m2, but it's been running forever. There are about 6000 nodes in the set and very heavy connections

Comment: You may want to calculate your sources counts by avoiding the matching completely and instead using `SIZE(()-[:ConnectsTo]->(m1)) as sources1Count, SIZE(()-[:ConnectsTo]->(m2)) as sources2Count`

Comment: InverseFalcon: Thanks for the suggestion - I haven't thought of that. I added it to the post. anarche: does this speed up the query?

Comment: @anarche - did the solution work for you? If not, can send your dataset (or an anonymized version of it) so that I can try to optimize the query?

Comment: @GáborSzárnyas Sorry for the delay, work travel. I was able to get it to run efficiently with a few additional filters, and for some reason, it now runs faster than it did earlier.

The code worked correctly, I'll post the edited version soon. Thank you for your answer and inputs.