# How to match exact all nodes from a query into another

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have 2 kind of nodes in my graph database: `(Rule)` and `(Constraint)` and 1 relationship `(Rule)->[:VALIDATED_IF]->(Constraint)` that has two attributes `{id, type}`
So my DB looks something like this:

```
(rule1)-[:VALIDATED_IF{id1,type1}]->(constraint1)
```

What I need is to find if there are two different `(rule)` that have the exact same `(constraint)` with the same `{id,type}` in the relationship.
How can I do that?

I tried something like:

```
MATCH (r1:Rule)-[p1:VALIDATED_IF]->(c:Constraint)<-[p2:VALIDATED_IF]-(r2:Rule)
WHERE r1.ruleName <> r2.ruleName
AND p1.id = p2.id
AND p2.type = p2.type
RETURN r1.ruleName, r2.ruleName, c.condition
```

But gives me rules with one of the same constraints

Comment: What exactly is `But gives me rules with one of the same constraints`?

Comment: It means it returns rules with one of the constraints in common, not all of them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I managed to solve by improving a bit this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40868958/match-nodes-with-common-nodes-with-a-relationship-neo4j-cypher):

```
MATCH (r1:Rule)-[v1:VALIDATED_IF]->(:Constraint)<-[v2:VALIDATED_IF]-(r2:Rule)
WHERE
     v1.id=v2.id AND v1.type = v2.type
MATCH
    (r1)-[:VALIDATED_IF]->(c1:Constraint),
    (r2)-[:VALIDATED_IF]->(c2:Constraint)
WITH
     r1, r2,
     COUNT(DISTINCT c1) AS c1Count, COUNT(DISTINCT c2) AS c2Count
MATCH (r1)-[v1:VALIDATED_IF]->(c:Constraint)<-[v2:VALIDATED_IF]-(r2)
WITH
     r1, r2,
     c1Count, c2Count, COUNT(c) AS commonConstraintsCount, 
     COLLECT(c.condition) AS cond // (5)\n" + 
WHERE
     ID(r1) < ID(r2) AND
     commonConstraintsCount = c1Count AND
     commonConstraintsCount = c2Count AND
     c1Count = c2Count
     RETURN r1.ruleName, r2.ruleName, cond
     ORDER BY r1.ruleName, r2.ruleName
```

So the improvement was checking that the number of common constraints was the same as the number of constraints each of the rules have, also check that the properties of the relationship :VALIDATED_IF are the same for both nodes on the first MATCH

Answer (score 0):

We can aggregate the :Rule nodes per constraint, rel id and rel type, this will also work when there are more than 2 :Rule nodes per constraint:

```
MATCH (rule:Rule)-[rel:VALIDATED_IF]->(c:Constraint)
WITH c, rel.id as relId, rel.type as relType, collect(rule) as rules
WHERE size(rules) > 1
RETURN c.condition as condition, [r in rules | r.ruleName] as rules
```

In Cypher, when you aggregate, the non-aggregation variables become the grouping key, so per row we'll have the constraint, the rel id and rel type, and all of the rules that have that same constraint, rel id, and rel type.

EDIT

Okay, sounds like you want to get the collection of rules that share the same collection of constraints. Does this work for you?

```
MATCH (rule:Rule)-[rel:VALIDATED_IF]->(c:Constraint)
WITH rule, rel.id as relId, rel.type as relType, c
ORDER BY id(c)
WITH rule, relId, relType, collect(c) as constraints
WITH constraints, collect(rule) as rules
WHERE size(rules) > 1
RETURN [c in constraints | c.condition] as conditions, [r in rules | r.ruleName] as rules
```

Comment: No quite what I want, that returns all the rules that are related to each constraint. What I need is all the rules that are related to the exact same group of constraints